# How to restart in android studio CountdownTimer inside of another CountdownTimer(Both are working perfectly)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make a question game to improve my skills. The user selects gameTime(in this case lets say 10 minutes) and for every question they have 10 seconds or whatever to respond. Both timers are working perfectly but how can I restart the 10 seconds counter when it reaches to an end and give place to the next question until the 10 minute counter finishes??

```
   private void startGameTimer(final TextView gameCountDown, final ArrayList<MusicSQLRow> arrayQuiz) {
// le agrego 2 segundos de delay para que le de tiempo al usuario de reaccionar


        new CountDownTimer(gameTime,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            gameCountDown.setText("Time Remaining: "+String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

                 // the questions begin adjusted by the SharedPreferences answer time, se abre otro thread para manejar la pregunta
                this.askQuestion(arrayQuiz);

            }

            // handles just one question
            private void askQuestion(ArrayList<MusicSQLRow> arrayQuiz) {

                new CountDownTimer(answerTime,1000){


                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        answerCountDown.setText("Next Question in: "+ TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) );


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                }.start();


            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
               //unhide buttons to go back to main menu or to play again(reset the activity, check if there's no problem with shared preferences when the activitie reloads)
            }

        }.start();

    }
```

Comment: That's what onFinish is for.

Comment: but what do i put onFinish??? that's the question......and I want to know what happens if the Game Timer reaches to an end and the question timer is 5 seconds away to expire....I do not want the little timer to keep on

Comment: Your game timer will finish and the question timer will continue in that case. As for what to call, you need to make a new method that does whatever check you need to do and sets up your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: try not to create anonymous instances of long running CountDownTimer, you won't be able to dispose of them and you will leak entire activity. Best option would be to create separate class files containing these timers.

```
CountDownTimer gameTimer, answerTimer;
boolean gameTimerIsRunning, answerTimerIsRunning;

public void startGame(){
    startGameTimer();
    startAnswerTimer();
}

public void startGameTimer(){
    gameTimer = new CountDownTimer(GAME_DURATION, TEXT_VIEW_UPDATE_RATE){

        @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            updateGameTextView(millisUntilFinished);
        }

        @Override public void onFinish() {
            gameTimerIsRunning = false;
            if(answerTimerIsRunning) answerTimer.cancel(); 
            handleEndOfTheGame();
        }

    };
    gameTimerIsRunning = true;
    gameTimer.start();
}

public void startAnswerTimer(){
    if(answerTimer==null) {
        answerTimer = new CountDownTimer(TIME_FOR_AN_ANSWER, TEXT_VIEW_UPDATE_RATE) {

            @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                updateAnswerTextView(millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override public void onFinish() {
                answerTimerIsRunning = false;

                if (gameTimerIsRunning) {
                    loadNewQuestion();
                    startAnswerTimer();
                }
        };
    }
    answerTimerIsRunning = true;
    answerTimer.start();
}
```

Don't forget to call gameTimer.cancel() and answerTimer.cancel() in your activity/fragment onPause().

Comment: Thanks for the help to both of you guys, your code looks really good. I'll try this when I get home tonight and tell you guys what happened. What do you mean by "you will leak the entire activity"???....And how should I separate these on different class files?....I ask this because I don't see the difference between the 2, they are 2 instances of the same class

Comment: By design, all inner anonymous classes hold reference to their enclosing instances. If not disposed of properly timer may hold strong reference to the activity never allowing it to be garbage collected.

Comment: I solved it, thanks to all. I leave the code that let you use a countdownTimer inside the timeFrame of another countdownTimer

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=81qnhtyy